# {{}} in ng-click & ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

This is the code of my HTML

```
<div id="container" ng-app="containArea" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="sidebody" class="block">
    <button 
      ng-repeat="shopli in shopName" 
      ng-click="openurl({{'\''+shopli.url+'\''}})" 
      class="btn_shopList">
      {{shopli.name}}
    </button>
</div>
 ........
</div>
```

And the JS here

```
var app = angular.module('containArea', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.shopName=[
        {
          "name":'momo購物網',
          "url":'https://buyforfun.biz/2LvEY'
        },
        {
          "name":'金石堂書局',
          "url":'https://joymall.co/2MX4o'
        }
    ]; 
    $scope.openurl = function(url){
         window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
});
```

The {{shopli.name}} output correctly

But if I click the button , nothing happened

Could anyone help me to fix it

Comment: why can't you send `ng-click="openurl(shopli.url)" ` directly?

Comment: It works,thank you

Comment: glad to be of help! cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value directly in `ng-click` function instead of using angular expression `{{}}`.

```
ng-click="openurl('\''+shopli.url+'\'')"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('containArea', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.shopName = [{
      "name": 'momo購物網',
      "url": 'https://buyforfun.biz/2LvEY'
    },
    {
      "name": '金石堂書局',
      "url": 'https://joymall.co/2MX4o'
    }
  ];
  $scope.openurl = function(url) {
    console.log(url);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" ng-app="containArea" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="sidebody" class="block">
    <button ng-repeat="shopli in shopName" ng-click="openurl(shopli.url)" class="btn_shopList">
      {{shopli.name}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still nothing happened

Comment: Still nothing happened https://upload.cc/i1/2018/11/22/03c6WG.png

Comment: @張睿玹 just use `ng-click="openurl(shopli.url)"` without quotes. That should work  for windows.open.

Comment: @   Shaheryar.Akram @Ankit Agarwal
 Thanks a lot ,it work.

Comment: @張睿玹 glad to help